# How to remove the difference in time with Epoch time?

Tags: c, time, epoch

I was trying to  find out the creation time of file from its inode. I have used gmtime() for converting into normal time. But there is a 6 hour 30 minute difference in time with that displayed by ls -l command.

Why is this so? How do I remove this difference?

Answer (score 2):

from **man gmtime**

```
   The  gmtime()  function  converts  the  calendar  time timep to broken-down time representation, expressed in Coordinated Universal Time
   (UTC).

   ...............

   The localtime() function converts the calendar time timep to broken-time representation, expressed  relative  to  the  user's  specified
   timezone.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you are using linux. In unix creation time is not stored; you only have time of last access (atime), time of last modification of contents (mtime), and time of last modification of the inode (ctime).

So checkout what you are retrieving from inode and comparing with ls -l